# iOS theme on desktop builds?

Tags: codenameone

Recently I created a desktop app with Codename One, that through REST calls implements the backend of a website. Since the graphics were relatively very simple, I could use `includeNativeBool: false;` and create the graphics from scratch, in order to have the desired graphic look.

Soon I will have to make another desktop app with Codename One, both for Windows and MacOS. In this new app, however, the graphics will be more complex and I don't think it's a good idea to create it from scratch. I wish I could use `includeNativeBool: true;` and have iOS graphics as a starting point (both on Windows and MacOS). Is it possible?

Note that when I tried to use the `desktop.theme` build hint it didn't work, but maybe I didn't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a theme file to the `desktop.theme` build hint. So just download the [native iOS theme](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Themes/iOS7Theme.res?raw=true) and place it under your native/javase directory. Then set the build hint as such: `desktop.theme=iOS7Theme`.